# MVC: When displaying Partial View's data in the pop up, the same data is displayed in the main view as well where Ajax.ActionLink() is defined

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, actionlink

I have MVC View, View1.

This view has a button built with `Ajax.ActionLink` logic.
I'm looking for the right way to display the data in a `Partial View` loaded into a pop up window. How can I do that?

Currently, the data is displayed, however it gets displayed in the main view (View1) right at the place where I defined `Ajax.ActionLink`

This is my code in the View1 where I do an Ajax call to show my `PartialView`:

```
Alax.ActionLink("Click here", "ShowPartialView","MyController", new AjaxOptions{....}, new class{....})
```

My Controller has the following logic that will display my `Partial View`:

```
public PartialViewResult ShowPartialView()
{
      return("_MyPartialView");
}
```

My Model has a definition of an Entity returned from the server that will contain a List of items to display in my partial view's table:

```
public MyEntity ObjectEntity {get;set}
```

My `Partial View` has a definition of a Table:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th></th>
       <th></th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
       </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

And a logic to get data with `Json`:

```
<script>
$.getJSON("MyController/GetData", function(result){
          ....Build the table from result
});
</script>
```

And then I define a method in My controller:

```
public JasonResult GetData()
{
       return Json(MyModel.ObjectEntitity.ListOfObjects);
}
```

Currently, the data is displayed in the pop up, however, it also gets displayed in the Main View (View1) exactly where I use Ajax.ActionLink()

Why is that, and what is the best way to accomplish what I need?

Comment: Why do you have `Ajax.ActionLink()` and `$.getJSON()` (both of which are making an ajax call)?

Comment: In my case, the `Ajax.ActionLink` calls Partial View and then Partial View gets displayed and tries to call method to get the data from the server. What is the better way to do it? I need to open a pop up with the data. Pop Up will have the Partial View that gets populated with the Grid data

Comment: Why don't you get the data in first call only by clicking `Ajax.ActionLink` and fill the the data in the table...??